# Shortcode for button with custom style

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have already added an link in my widget
eg:

```
 <a target="_blank" href="google.com" class="a-button">Learn More</a>
```

I need an shortcode  like this

```
[button link="google.com" value="Learn More"]
```

If i paste this shortcode in widget, page and post, link must appear

Style must be same as above  tag

Current Code:

```
function button_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'url' => '#' ), $atts ) );
    return '<a href="'.$url.'" class="a-button">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode('button', 'button_shortcode');
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Did you create the shortcode yourself?

Comment: No i need to create a shortcode like this

Comment: yes now i have created

Comment: Show us the code you are facing problem with?

Answer (score 2):

Basic shortcode will look like this:

```
function a_button_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   extract($atts);
   return '<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_attr($link) . '" class="a-button">' . esc_attr($value) .   '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'button', 'a_button_shortcode' );
```

You can read more on shortcode api on: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

In order to make your widget with shortcodes should use do_shortcode( $content ) function inside update method of your widget.

Like this:

```
function update( $old_instance, $new_instance) {
   $new_instance['content'] = do_shortcode($new_instance['content']);
   return $new_instance;
}
```

Or use a plugin that will make it for default widgets like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-in-sidebar-widgets/

Comment: I am not using any Plugins. i need to first create an shortcode for the link with style?

Comment: I updated my anwser. I hope everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_shortcode("init" ,"add_custom_shortcode");

function add_custom_shortcode()
{
     add_shortcode('button', 'buttonShortcode');
}

function buttonShortcode($atts, $text='') {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'url' => '#' ), $atts ) );
    return '<a href="'.$url.'" class="a-button">' . do_shortcode($text) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all, i tried out this one

```
function button_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'url' => '#'
), $atts ) );
return '<a href="'.$url.'" class="a-button">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode('button', 'button_shortcode');\
```

For shortcode support in widget paste below line in functions.php

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

created shortcode:

```
[button url="google.com"]Download[/button]
```